# Child-Parent-Communication: Method not found?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to setup child-parent communication with nuxtjs. This is my child:

```
    <div>
        <b-nav-item @click="clicked" :class="{active: active}">{{item.name}}</b-nav-item>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            item:{
                required: true
            },
            active:{
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            clicked() {             
                this.$emit('clicki');
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Parent:

```
    <NavigationElement v-for="item in clients" :key="item.id" :item="item" @clicki="showClient" :active="currentClient._id==item._id"><NavigationElement>
</template>
<script>
    import NavigationElement from '~/components/NavigationElement.vue'
    import TopicElement from '~/components/TopicElement.vue'
    export default {
        middleware: ['check-auth', 'auth'],
        computed: {clients() {return this.$store.getters.getClients}},
        methods(){
            showClient(){
                console.log("click");
            // this.currentClient = client;
            }
        },
</script>
```

I get this error:

> Property or method "showClient" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Can someone help me and explain why I get it?

Answer (score 1):

```
</template>
<script>
   import NavigationElement from '~/components/NavigationElement.vue'
   import TopicElement from '~/components/TopicElement.vue'
   export default {
       middleware: ['check-auth', 'auth'],
       computed: {clients() {return this.$store.getters.getClients}},
       methods:{
           showClient(){
               console.log("click");
           // this.currentClient = client;
           }
       },
</script>
```

methods has to be an object not a function.